# How to run jasmine describe test cases on a click of button

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am running multiple test cases in chrome in normal mode. At last there will be a button in UI and ask the user wether, they want to run this big test cases(which will take more time).

```
<button onclick="transitionTestCases()"> Run Big test cases</button>
function transitionTestCases(){
 describe("abc",function(){
   it("big test case",function(){
       console.log("big test cases")
   })
 })
}
```

And i want to execute "abc" describe on the function call. It is returning a object as suite. Any idea how to run it.